# Wearable listener

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I am trying to execute a command in Android by sending trigger signal from watch. My phone part is like below.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Service;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageEvent;

public abstract class WearableListenerServiceForWear
    extends Service implements  MessageApi.MessageListener {
  private static final String HELLO_WORLD_WEAR_PATH = "/hello-world-wear";

  @Override
  public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {

    if (messageEvent.getPath().equals(HELLO_WORLD_WEAR_PATH)) {
      try {
        command
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      ;//null pointer check in case package name was not found
    } else {
      Log.e("TAG",
              "Failed to send message with status code: ");
    }
  }
}
```

And in the phone part I am sending message using this code:

```
private void sendMessage() {
        if (mNode != null && mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
          Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, mNode.getId(), HELLO_WORLD_WEAR_PATH, null)
              .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<MessageApi.SendMessageResult>() {
                @Override public void onResult(MessageApi.SendMessageResult sendMessageResult) {
                  if (!sendMessageResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Log.e("TAG",
                        "Failed to send message with status code: " + sendMessageResult.getStatus()
                            .getStatusCode());
                  }
                }
              });
        } else {
          //Improve your code
        }
      }
```

There is no error showing. Both of the App is running fine in the watch and the phone. But the command is not triggering. Is there anything wrong in the code?

Comment: What is `command`?

Comment: I am gonna put some command there. Like showing an image

Comment: So, nothing happens at all? `Log.e` not printed? Have you tried logging anything at `//Improve your code`?

Comment: Why not use `WearableListenerService`? https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events.html#Listen